# How to move the data in one array to a separate array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamic, foreach

I am using JavaScript for this.

This is what I have currently in my array

```
0 "mariam"
1 "jibrin"
2 "maths"
3 "Primary_1"
4 "period_3"
5 "Monday"
6 "subject=maths?name=mariam&jibrin "
7 "zainab"
8 "usman"
9 "maths"
10 "Nursery_2"
11 "period_3"
12 "Wednesday"
13 "subject=maths?name=zainab&usman "
```

Snapshot for better view can be found [here](https://gyazo.com/f4b0e59f0daa323e73bb8d6cba1fa6e3)

What I want to do is loop through this array split it where there is a value containing "subject=" and move the all the values up to that point into a new array.

So everything from index 0 to 6 will be moves to a new array from here since the value at index 6 will match the condition. 
This will apply for the rest.

So this is the code I have so far:

```
var your_object = JSON.parse(response); // here I will have a JSON
var splitter = String(your_object).split(","); 

var returnArray = [];
    var tmp = [];
    $(splitter).each(function (i,v) {
        console.log(i,v);
        if (v.includes("subject=")) {
            //console.log("FOUND", i);
        }
    });
```

I am not sure how to go about moving it into a new array and dynamically handle this. Json at the minute only passed a full total size of 14 however it can be higher later on.

If a condition matches (i.e. value contains "subject=" then everything from the index at the start at the point where it matched needs moving to a new array which have to be dynamic.

I know how to remove from the current array but not sure how to dynamically move it into a new one.

If I did not made myself clear please ask and thank You

Comment: Given the example input you provided, what output do you expect?

Comment: I expect the output to be an array holding 6 values however it has to be dynamic array. So if i have 14 values in the first array there will be 2 arrays will be produced because the 6the and the 13th index will start of with subject=

Comment: Does that make sense i am not sure if it has ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the item contains the subject substring and change the array for the result.

```js
var data = ["mariam", "jibrin", "maths", "Primary_1", "period_3", "Monday", "subject=maths?name=mariam&jibrin ", "zainab", "usman", "maths", "Nursery_2", "period_3", "Wednesday", "subject=maths?name=zainab&usman "],
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        if (a.slice(0, 8) === 'subject=' && i + 1 < aa.length) {
            r.push([]);
        }
        return r;
    }, [[]]);
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```